# default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

When I run `vagrant up`, I get:

```
D:\GitHub\website\rails-dev-box>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty32' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 3000 => 1234 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
```

This warning will be for ever ..

What I've noticed is that if I started the VM manually ( without vagrant ) it will work without any delay, but only If I enabled Adapter 2 at VM settings like this:[image]
How can I enable Adapter 2 of VM when using `vagrant up` ?

**EDIT**

`Vagrantfile` is:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
#     config.vm.network :hostonly, "192.168.50.4"
end



Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|

  config.vm.box      = 'ubuntu/trusty32'
  config.vm.hostname = 'rails-dev-box'
# config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant/web" #, type: "nfs"

config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.gui = true
end

 config.vm.boot_timeout = 120

 #  config.winnfsd.uid = 1
   # config.winnfsd.gid = 1

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 1234

  config.vm.provision :shell, path: 'bootstrap.sh', keep_color: true
end
```

Comment: could you please remove whole part of  `Vagrant::Config.run do |config|#     config.vm.network :hostonly, "192.168.50.4"
end` and try again?

Comment: I tried, but I got the same result ..

Comment: Since you actived GUI, Do you see anything hold on Virtualbox? Your `Vagrantfile` looks fine for me. I recommend 1) try with different image (for example, `precise64`). 2) restart your machine. 3) clean your virtualbox environment and try again.

Answer (score 18):

For me it turned out that patience was the answer.
I was getting the message (I got it 12 times) but I waited a couple of minutes and then it succeeded.
When you say "this warning will be for ever .."  How long did you wait?

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'phusion/ubuntu-14.04-amd64' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
    default: Adapter 3: hostonly
    default: Adapter 4: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 3000 => 3334 (adapter 1)
    default: 1080 => 1082 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Exporting NFS shared folders...
==> default: Preparing to edit /etc/exports. Administrator privileges will be required...
Password:
==> default: Mounting NFS shared folders...
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: stop: Unknown instance:
==> default: mongod start/running, process 8424
```

Comment: This happened again and after about 5 mins it succeeded.

Comment: Same for me. Had to be patient. I asked virtualbox to show me a screen of this vm, and I saw that the boot was just slow, and the ssh service was not  ready.

Comment: Does not seem like a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution per-say, but I have found that when I timed out after getting that message ~20 times that I could `vagrant halt` the machine (which forces it as there is no ssh connection that can be made), ran `vagrant up`, it worked only giving me the warning twice.

So... turn it off and on again? So stupid but does seem to work untill there's an actual solution.